# Не нужно ли двоеточие после ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ?

Tags: двоеточие, перечисление

... где мусульманское население является а) исторически коренным и б) быстро развивающимся.
Не нужно ли двоеточие после ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно, если список вынесен в перечень, поскольку в таком случае перечень [разъясняет и продолжает](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/83-rubric-77) то, о чём говорится в тексте.

Впрочем, если перечень приводится не списком, а [идёт подбором в строку](http://ktvd.ru/kak-oformit-spisok/), двоеточие также необходимо.

Comment: В Вашей ссылке я не нашёл явного правила для "в подбор".

Comment: В первом предложении сказано: "...впрочем, иногда и в строчку...". Из этого следует, что правила одинаковы для каждого случая, разница лишь в том, что подбор после двоеточия, состоящий из двух элементов, не разделяется знаками препинания.